# Ksoap 3.0.0 not work with basic authentication

Tags: java, eclipse, ksoap2

I try to use `KSOAP2` with Basic Authentication. I´m download `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, `ksoap2-extras-3.0.0.jar`, `ksoap2-extra-ntlm-3.0.0.jar`. I Tried to use the code below:

```
ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + 
org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes())));
```

it's generate the error:

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 401
ERROR:java.io.IOException:HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 401
```

I Tried to use the code below too:

```
HttpTransportBasicAuth androidHttpTpAut = new HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, "user", "password");
androidHttpTpAut.getServiceConnection().connect();
```

again not work, generate the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransport
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Anybody do this work fine ?

Answer (score 4):

After many test, I found that the code below need to change:

```
ArrayList headerProperty = new ArrayList();
headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("user:password".getBytes())));

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Change above `androidHttpTransport.call()` to below polymorphic method:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerProperty);
```

It´s necessary put the parameter `headerProperty` in method `androidHttpTransport.call`.
And, I use only `ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. It worked in my case, hope it will help you too.

Create a class called `HttpTransportBasicAuth`

```
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE; 
import java.io.*;  

public class HttpTransportBasicAuth extends HttpTransportSE {
    private String username;   
    private String password;   

    public HttpTransportBasicAuth(String url, String username, String password) {   
        super(url);   
        this.username = username;   
        this.password = password;   
    }   

    public ServiceConnection getServiceConnection() throws IOException {   
        ServiceConnectionSE midpConnection = new ServiceConnectionSE(url);   
        addBasicAuthentication(midpConnection);   
        return midpConnection;   
    }   

    protected void addBasicAuthentication(ServiceConnection midpConnection) throws IOException {   
        if (username != null && password != null) {   
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(username);   
            buf.append(':').append(password);   
            byte[] raw = buf.toString().getBytes();   
            buf.setLength(0);   
            buf.append("Basic ");   
            org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(raw, 0, raw.length, buf);   
            midpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", buf.toString());   
        }   
    }
}
```

And then, change the following in your proxy class (refer the proxy class below)

```
protected org.ksoap2.transport.Transport createTransport()
{
    return new HttpTransportBasicAuth(url,username,password);
}
```

**Proxy class**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.AttributeContainer;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

public class Z_WS_SCAN_REPLENISHMENT
{
    interface IWcfMethod
    {
        ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope CreateSoapEnvelope() throws java.lang.Exception;

        Object ProcessResult(ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope envelope,SoapObject result) throws java.lang.Exception;
    }

    String url="http://example.com/z_ws_scan_replenishment/200/z_ws_scan_replenishment/z_ws_scan_replenishment";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    int timeOut=60000;
    public List< HeaderProperty> httpHeaders;

    IServiceEvents callback;
    public Z_WS_SCAN_REPLENISHMENT(){}

    public Z_WS_SCAN_REPLENISHMENT (IServiceEvents callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    public Z_WS_SCAN_REPLENISHMENT(IServiceEvents callback,String url)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Z_WS_SCAN_REPLENISHMENT(IServiceEvents callback,String url,int timeOut)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.url = url;
        this.timeOut=timeOut;
    }

    protected org.ksoap2.transport.Transport createTransport()
    {
        return  new HttpTransportBasicAuth(url,username,password);
    }

    protected ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope createEnvelope()
    {
        return new ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope();
    }

    protected void sendRequest(String methodName,ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope envelope,org.ksoap2.transport.Transport transport) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        transport.call(methodName, envelope,httpHeaders);
    }

    Object getResult(Class destObj,SoapObject source,String resultName,ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope __envelope) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        if (source.hasProperty(resultName))
        {
            Object j=source.getProperty(resultName);
            if(j==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Object instance=__envelope.get((AttributeContainer)j,destObj);
            return instance;
        }
        else if( source.getName().equals(resultName)) {
            Object instance=__envelope.get(source,destObj);
            return instance;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Bapireturn1 ZScanReplenishment(final String ILgnum,final String IPernr,final String IScannedId,final String IScannedLgpl ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        return (Bapireturn1)execute(new IWcfMethod()
        {
            @Override
            public ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope CreateSoapEnvelope(){

                ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope __envelope = createEnvelope();
                SoapObject __soapReq = new SoapObject("urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style", "ZScanReplenishment");
                __envelope.setOutputSoapObject(__soapReq);



                PropertyInfo __info=null;
                __info = new PropertyInfo();
                __info.namespace="";
                __info.name="ILgnum";
                __info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                __info.setValue(ILgnum);
                __soapReq.addProperty(__info);
                __info = new PropertyInfo();
                __info.namespace="";
                __info.name="IPernr";
                __info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                __info.setValue(IPernr);
                __soapReq.addProperty(__info);
                __info = new PropertyInfo();
                __info.namespace="";
                __info.name="IScannedId";
                __info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                __info.setValue(IScannedId);
                __soapReq.addProperty(__info);
                __info = new PropertyInfo();
                __info.namespace="";
                __info.name="IScannedLgpl";
                __info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                __info.setValue(IScannedLgpl);
                __soapReq.addProperty(__info);
                return __envelope;
            }

            @Override
            public Object ProcessResult(ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope __envelope,SoapObject __result)throws java.lang.Exception {
                return (Bapireturn1)getResult(Bapireturn1.class,__result,"EReturn",__envelope);
            }
        },"");
    }



    protected Object execute(IWcfMethod wcfMethod,String methodName) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        org.ksoap2.transport.Transport __httpTransport=createTransport();
        ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope __envelope=wcfMethod.CreateSoapEnvelope();
        sendRequest(methodName, __envelope, __httpTransport);
        Object __retObj = __envelope.bodyIn;
        if (__retObj instanceof SoapFault){
            SoapFault __fault = (SoapFault)__retObj;
            throw convertToException(__fault,__envelope);
        }else{
            SoapObject __result=(SoapObject)__retObj;
            return wcfMethod.ProcessResult(__envelope,__result);
        }
    }

    java.lang.Exception convertToException(SoapFault fault,ExtendedSoapSerializationEnvelope envelope)
    {
        return new java.lang.Exception(fault.faultstring);
    }
}
```

These changes did the magic for me. Hope it will work for you as well.